# Select unique element by attribute using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

My XML has some weird structures. It is being generated from a CMS driving a website, but we need to use the XML output from the database to create print documents in Adobe InDesign.

I need to select some content that is wrapped in span tags that have specific classes but my XSLT is not working.

Here is the raw XML output:

```
<newsItem>
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet[
<!ENTITY bull   "&#8226;">
]>
<inlineXml>
  <h2>Appointments</h2>
<p><span class="PB-biz red bullet">&bull;</span> <span><strong>John Smith</strong></span> interim president and CEO was named to the permanent     position.</p>    
<p><span class="PB-biz red bullet">&bull;</span> Hospital announced that <span><strong>James Williams</strong></span> will become division president .</p>
</inlineXml>
</newsItem>
```

Here is the XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="newsItem"> <newsItem><xsl:apply-templates/></newsItem></xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="p">
<p><xsl:apply-templates/></p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="span[@class='PB-biz']">
<bull><xsl:apply-templates/></bull>">
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="span/strong"><xsl:text> </xsl:text><biz-name><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/></biz-name><xsl:text> </xsl:text></xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here's the desired output:

```
<newsItem>
<inlineXml>
<h2>Appointments</h2>
<p><bull>&bull;</bull> <biz-name>John Smith</biz-name> interim president and CEO was named to the permanent position.</p>    
<p><bull>&bull;</bull> Hospital announced that <biz-name>James Williams</biz-name> will become division president.</p>
</inlineXml>
</newsItem>
```

I can't get the selection to work for the bullet entity element.

Thanks

Comment: Is that your exact, complete XML input? You cannot use an entity like `&bull;` in XML without declaring it first.

Comment: Sorry, it was in the XML, but I just didn't show it. The source is corrected now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class in the XML is 'PB-biz red bullet'. You match on class 'PB-biz'. As those are not the same, it matches none. Change the XSLT to match the exact attribute value of class.

Comment: So, you have to use all three classes? I've never seen that before. Do you write them as in CSS with periods, like PB-biz.red.bullet? Or just leave the spaces?

Comment: I tried it with spaces and it worked. What a hoot. So, when selecting a node with multiple classes, there's no way to match it on only one class?

Comment: Indeed... XSLT is no CSS. So when writing matches you need to specify full attribute values. What you might do is mach on the presence of the class attribute and do a contains check in the template itself.

Comment: @JimMaivald In XML, an attribute contains a single value. You can match on a partial value using the contains() function - but unless you take extra care, you you can easily get a false positive. Your data provider should not place multiple values in a single attribute, but use multiple elements instead.